# An error occurred while trying to retrieve additional information from the Solr server: "401" Status: Unauthorized: Unauthorized

Tags: drupal, solr, http-status-code-404, unauthorized

After configuring the solr server, the solr server could be reached

```
Connection:The Solr server could be reached (latency: 4.6079622039795 ms).
```

But the extra information gives me :

```
An error occurred while trying to retrieve additional information from the Solr server: "401" Status: Unauthorized: Unauthorized<html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/7.0.28 - Error report</title><style><!--H1 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:22px;} H2 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:16px;} H3 {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;font-size:14px;} BODY {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:black;background-color:white;} B {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;color:white;background-color:#525D76;} P {font-family:Tahoma,Arial,sans-serif;background:white;color:black;font-size:12px;}A {color : black;}A.name {color : black;}HR {color : #525D76;}--></style> </head><body><h1>HTTP Status 401 - </h1><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><p><b>type</b> Status report</p><p><b>message</b> <u></u></p><p><b>description</b> <u>This request requires HTTP authentication ().</u></p><HR size="1" noshade="noshade"><h3>Apache Tomcat/7.0.28</h3></body></html>.
```

I can't figure out what the problem is. Someone knows how to solve this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The error is generated by Tomcat - the application server that hosts Solr (and possibly other Java web applications). It has been configured to require authenticated clients (through HTTP auth) from the host you're requesting the content from (or for accessing the Solr resource).

You'll have to reconfigure Tomcat to allow connections to Solr or supply a username / password (.. and make sure you can access the URL to the Solr server in your own browser first).

Answer (score 0):

I resolved it by inserting a username and password in the section:

BASIC HTTP AUTHENTICATION
If your Solr server is protected by basic HTTP authentication, enter the login data here.

However I get a new error:

```
You are using an incompatible schema.xml configuration file. Please follow the instructions in the INSTALL.txt file for setting up Solr.
```